# Scheduler not hitting the methods

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I am facing issue, scheduler is not hitting the method using the scheduler Agent. Please find below script:

Config:

```
<scheduling>
    <!-- default agents go here... -->
    <agent type="******.Web.Controllers.IW.GenerateExcelutility, ******.Web.Controllers" method="GenerateExcelAndSendMail" interval="00:02:00">
    </agent>
</scheduling>
```

Class:

```
public class GenerateExcelutility
{
    public void GenerateExcelAndSendMail()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props) …………………………………….
    }
}
```

Comment: If you open [Sitecore URL]/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx in a browser, is your agent visible under the /configuration/sitecore/scheduling node?

Comment: Could you please verify from show config that the below processor is present. This is responsible for Initialize the Scheduler. <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeScheduler, Sitecore.Kernel"> If this is not there, you need to identify is there any patch file which delete this processor.

Answer (score 6):

Your class needs to be non-generic. I recommend inheriting from `BaseAgent`.

Right now, Sitecore can't instantiate your class. I don't know exactly how your class is defined, but I know it has a `generics` component to it, based on this line of code.

```
System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
```

`T` would be the generic component in a class declaration like this `public class MyExcelAgent<T> where T: something`.  This cannot be instantiated by Sitecore for an agent.

Change it to something like

```
public class MyExcelAgent : Sitecore.Tasks.BaseAgent
{
    public void GenerateExcelAndSendMail()
    {
        .... your code here
    }
}
```

(and the code you've posted can't be the actual code - T would be undeclared in this case)

Comment: thanks for pointing out that you cant instantiate your class have the same sort of problem but dont know how to get around it. So my agent class doesnt instatiate anything but want to calls and use methods in other classes that do as the other classes have got interfaces i need to use how do i get around this :(.